# What could cause mysql privileges for a user to be lost in a docker container database?

Tags: mysql, docker

I use docker compose to run Ubuntu and MySQL, plus other stuff, for local development. I typically create multiple test databases with a single test user, like

```
create database d9_groups_g5_db;
grant all privileges on d9_groups_g5_db.* to 'd9user'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

Which works fine, except that lately it seems to be "forgetting" the privileges I've granted. I start and stop and repull and rebuild Docker frequently, and I assume that's related. This is the service definition for mysql in my docker-compose.yml file:

```
  aspodb:
    container_name: aspodb
    image: mysql:8
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    command: mysqld --max_allowed_packet=256M
    networks:
      - asponet
    volumes:
      - aspodata:/var/lib/mysql
      - aspodatatmp:/var/tmp
      - ./setup/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./setup/mysqlcnf/aspodb.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/aspodb.cnf


...

volumes:
  aspodata: {}
  aspodatatmp: {}

networks:
  asponet:
```

This doesn't apply consistently. Some databases never forget their users, some always seem to do so. It's not a big issue, since I can just recreate the privileges, but I'm curious why it might be happening.

What I did:
I started my Docker containers and created a database in mysql, granting all privileges on the database to an existing user. I stopped the Docker containers, stopped Docker, restarted Docker, rebuilt the containers, and restarted them.

What I expected:
I expected the existing user to have all privileges on the database.

What happened instead:
The user and the database both still existed, but the user did not have privileges on the database.